# MaterializeCSS autocomplete MySQL data to JSON with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, autocomplete, materialize

how can I make the data display from my Database like this?

```
"Text": null,
"Text2": null,
"Text3": 'http://placehold.it/250x250',
"Text4": null,
```

It's from MaterializeCSS

I have no idea how to change my data from MySQL to JSON and **specialy** like this.
Can you help me please?